# Problem with operator?

Tags: c#

I am writing following code:

```
_normDoc = value as NormDoc;
  if(_normDoc != null)
   {
     ucRusKazTextBoxesAnnotation.Controls["tbNameRu"].Text = _normDoc.AddInfoRu ?? string.Empty;
   }
```

I think that if `_normDoc.AddInfoRu == null` then `ucRusKazTextBoxesAnnotation.Controls["tbNameRu"].Text` will be equal empty string.
  But I am got  error: `NullReferenceException`.
Can you explain me why?

PS. ucRusKazTextBoxesAnnotation not equal null;

**EDIT**: Sorry,  I find error, yes, tbNameRu not found, because they are inside Panel control.

Comment: The control being returned from the array index is null?

Comment: I would think that it can't find Controls["tbNameRu"]. Make sure that your name is correct.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the line down into several discrete steps? You're checking _normDoc for null, why not explicitly check `_normDoc.AddInfoRu` and `ucRusKazTextBoxesAnnotation.Controls["tbNameRu"]` for null as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ucRusKazTextBoxesAnnotation.Controls["tbNameRu"]` could be `null` just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that  `ucRusKazTextBoxesAnnotation.Controls["tbNameRu"]` is not `null`.